# Firemonkey possible bug with drag and drop

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have noticed that there is something wrong when I use the `OnDragDrop` event and the `OnDragOver` event. Look at this piece of code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1DragDrop(Sender: TObject; const [Ref] Data: TDragObject;
  const [Ref] Point: TPointF);
var t,d: TButton;
begin

 T := TButton(Sender);
 D := TButton(Data.Source);
 T.data := T.data + D.data;
 Score(T.data);
 D.data := 0;
 T.isOk := true;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1DragOver(Sender: TObject; const [Ref] Data: TDragObject;
  const [Ref] Point: TPointF; var Operation: TDragOperation);
begin

 if ((Sender is TButton) and (Data.Source is TButton) and not(Sender = Data.Source)
     and (TButton(Sender).Text = TButton(Data.Source).Text) and (TButton(Data.Source).Text <> '')) then
  begin
   operation := TDragOperation.Move;
  end
 else
  begin
   operation := TDragOperation.None;
  end;

end;
```

This code is related to the form that you can see in this picture below:

[image]

This is a grid layout with some buttons inside; Button1 is the top-left one and all the other buttons have the events `OnDragDrop` and `OnDragOver` pointing to Button1 events. For example [look](http://prntscr.com/d7zzwr).

When I run the program under Windows (target platform win32 bit) I am able to drag and drop the buttons in the grid using the cursor and the mouse. The problem comes out when I move to android because on my mobile I cannot drag and drop buttons. Any idea?

This is a multi-device app built with Firemonkey. I was thinking that I have to declare the DragDrop and DragOver event for every button instead of making a reference to Button1. Could this be?

Comment: AFAIK, IFMXDragDropService is implemented for Windows and Mac only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug and you can find the reason [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXDragDropService) in the documentation; the DragDropService is not implemented in the android platform.

> You can use IFMXDragDropService in both Windows and OS X

If you want to make a test I suggest you to try with this line:

```
if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXDragDropService) then
 begin
  //test code
 end;
```

In order to be sure that you can use the `IFMXDragDropService` service, first test whether it is supported.